# How to fade in image in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to on page load select a random image from either 1) a set like xml file or directory and randomly choose one and fade it in at medium speed.

Anyone?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you after someone to code the whole thing for you?

Comment: You want the whole thing or just fading in the image?

Comment: Javascript only or javascript + some server-side scripting? Btw: jQuery API documentation is pretty clear about the fadeIn functon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("pictures.json", function(json){
    var pics = json.pictures;
    var pic = Math.floor(Math.random()*pics.length);
    $("img", { src: pics[pic] }).load(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    }).appendTo("body");
});
```

pictures.json

```
{ pictures: [ "apple.jpg", "pear.jpg", "orange.jpg", "bannana.jpg", "grapefruit.jpg" ] }
```

Comment: No clue how to implement this.. Kinda need some html too :)

Comment: I figured something like this, since you never indicated you'd tried anything. Well, you could use a JSON file ('pictures.json') to store the names of every image (etc. "apple.jpg"), then with jQuery get and loop through that list of images, pick a random one, append it to the `body` and fade it in...that's what my code does. ATM it needs no HTML.

Comment: How do I call this 'json' request within a file though?

Comment: Make sure you include jQuery in your HTML page, then do `<script type="text/javascript">/* Code here */</script>` in your `<head>`

Comment: How do I call the 'pictures.json' though?

Comment: `pictures.json` is a file, you would just save it somewhere on your server, in the same folder as the JS script. jQuery has a function called `$.getJSON` which loads a JSON file (like in the example) and returns it as an object (in our case, the `json` variable).